# Resolving conflicting functionality in decoupled components

Tags: c#, overriding, components

I've been looking into more strict component based designs in Unity3D. I've been using a space invaders clone as a practice project. On my player object it has components: PlayerInput, HorizontalVelocity as well as the usual suspects like renderers.

I am using a mediator system for communication, so when an arrow key is pressed, the PlayerInput class creates an event which is then broadcast via the mediator to the velocity.

Now I want to add a HorizontalBounds class that stops it moving too far left or right. But there is a conflict: Velocity and Horizontal Bounds are each trying to move the transform in different ways concurrently. I can think of a few options of resolving this conflict:

**The bounds component constantly checks the transform** and if it is out of bounds it pushes it back in bounds. This is horrible as we have the velocity component moving it one way, and the bounds component moving it back, every single frame.

**Make a VelocityWithBounds component derived from Velocity** (or implements a velocity interface if we are trying to avoid inheritance?). The issue here is you are putting two components together. If you want to remove the bounds, you can't just get rid of that part (you could set it to bounds off but it would still be there). You would have to destroy everything and replaces it with a new velocity component. I'm not sure if this is going to cause any significant issues, but it seems inelegant.

**Give the bounds component some way of overriding the velocity components functionality during run time.** This seems like the most elegant solution but probably the hardest to implement. You would have to decouple them in such a way that velocity doesn't know its being overridden.
This is just one example problem. Are there any best practices for this kind of problem or should it be solved case by case?

Comment: Have you tried setting dynamically restriction position (if not velocity) using Mathf.Min(float a, float b); ? 
Can you explain, why are you so interested in playing with velocity only i.e giving counter or negative velocity to stop the ship from moving?

Comment: In a lot of component design its traditional to for a "velocity" component to control the movement of an object. If you like you can just think of it as a "movementController" component.

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "setting dynamically" but the fundamental problem is that we essentially have two independent components trying to produce opposite effects. Sort of an unstoppable force/immovable object scenario. The velocity / bounding is just an example of this type of problem. It could also be that two separate components were trying to change a sprite to different colors.

Comment: I have a solution in mind but before that I need to ask you whether you have an option to refactor the code of those two components at this point in your project?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have the luxury to refactor your code design, consider following options as an example:

**Superposition principle:**

```
F(v1+v2)=F(v1)+F(v2)  Additivity <= should apply better in your case
y ( x , t ) = y m sin ( k 1 x - w1 t ) + y m sin ( k 2 x + w 2 t ) 

w1 = velocity component 1
w2 = velocity component 2
x = phase
```

Create a space or function y(x,t) that directly drives the velocity of your ship

**Refinement Solution (my version):**

When you have two Identities/Spaces defining each other (component being in your case), it is always best to create a third Identity/Space such that third Identity/Space depends on first two.
In other words, break down the space [s0] into subspaces [s1 and s2] while doing so the result would be [s1 and s2] will have a common input and output Type (very important).

Break down the functionality of your ship into two, one that bounds your ship
and other that controls the acceleration. Two different gameobjects will be needed.

Since you have 2 decoupled components defining the velocity of an entity, I would suggest make the **bounds** move with that controlled entity. So this would mean for example: your ship loses velocity exponentially AND **acceleration** as it approaches the bounds however if you allow more acceleration, it begins to tag along the **bounds**.  Sounds drastic but that will give you additional control. Infact all you have to do is set the MAX acceleration to not exceed the needed acceleration to move the bound.

Comment: If you need further clarification, for Refinement Solution, it will take me some time.

Comment: What I've been doing is sort of along the lines of what you are suggesting.  Each component that can affect the say, velocity, would have a priority. The effects would all be sent to an intermediate component which would sort out all the priorities, and then only that component would be allowed to directly alter transform.

Comment: As long as you are satisfied with the result, you approach is good! However, as a good samaritan, I am still gonna lay down following recommendations:
1) Use of continuous function over discreet is ideally suitable for your case
2) Directly altering the Transform (i.e Position & Rotation) should be avoided in your case, using Rigidbody.Velocity is idiomatic.

Comment: I'll take those into account N_E. Talking to someone else he had a good solution using ECS. Basically, you have a System that alters the transforms. In this System you would have functionality to check if the entity you are altering has a bounds component. 

This is more or less what I was looking for. You now have a way to override behaviors, because those behaviors aren't in the components anymore. This is actually really similar to my idea of a mediator that is the only thing allowed to alter the transform, and it gets values form others